# CBCentralManager not calling didDiscoverPeripheral method Even Peripherals are active

Tags: ios, iphone, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

When App opens the first time it is successfully detecting Peripherals and when I rescan it will detecting perfectly again. when I trying to connect to it. `didDisconnectPeripheral` is getting called that I understand but after that when I scan (without restart app) again `didDiscover` peripheral method not getting called, please let me know if anyone has any idea. do I have to do something after `didDisconnectPeripheral` called.

Comment: Did you try disconnecting manually before reconnecting ?

Comment: Are you setting `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` to true or false?

Comment: Helo Gihan ..the problem is not connecting at all ..and calling didDisconnectPeripheral when try to connect. also not calling didDisconnectPeripheral and didDiscoverServices too

Comment: Hello DonMag .. Yes I tried but no use.. it is scanning when app restarts other wise not.